# When starting the application or compiling JSP via ant, Tomcat 7 Jasper complains about superfluous or misplaced JAR file. I got below message

Tags: tomcat, struts2

> May 03, 2014 3:31:37 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache
>   tldScanJar INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained
>   no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of
>   JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping
>   unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP
>   compilation time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tomcat 8 enable debug logging to list unneeded jars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821865/tomcat-8-enable-debug-logging-to-list-unneeded-jars)